# How to use Emgu.cv for Unknown Person?

Tags: c#, emgucv, face-recognition

I'm Using Emgu.cv for face recognition application. which stores faces images in database and tell the name of picture after recognition. My problem is that it does not tell about unknown person but it automatically match the most relevant face from database and tells the wrong name.

I want to display "unknown" string for unknown persons. I used the following code:

```
  public String Recognize(Image<Gray, Byte> image)
  {
     int index;
     float eigenDistance;
     String label;
     FindMostSimilarObject(image, out index, out eigenDistance, out label);

     return (_eigenDistanceThreshold <= 0 || eigenDistance < _eigenDistanceThreshold )  ? _labels[index] : String.Empty;
  }


  public EigenObjectRecognizer(Image<Gray, Byte>[] images, String[] labels, double eigenDistanceThreshold, ref MCvTermCriteria termCrit)
  {
     Debug.Assert(images.Length == labels.Length, "The number of images should equals the number of labels");
     Debug.Assert(eigenDistanceThreshold >= 0.0, "Eigen-distance threshold should always >= 0.0");

     CalcEigenObjects(images, ref termCrit, out _eigenImages, out _avgImage);

     /*
     _avgImage.SerializationCompressionRatio = 9;

     foreach (Image<Gray, Single> img in _eigenImages)
         //Set the compression ration to best compression. The serialized object can therefore save spaces
         img.SerializationCompressionRatio = 9;
     */

     _eigenValues = Array.ConvertAll<Image<Gray, Byte>, Matrix<float>>(images,
         delegate(Image<Gray, Byte> img)
         {
            return new Matrix<float>(EigenDecomposite(img, _eigenImages, _avgImage));
         });

     _labels = labels;

     _eigenDistanceThreshold = eigenDistanceThreshold;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the EigenObjectRecognizer returns a`String.Empty`

```
       return (_eigenDistanceThreshold <= 0 || _eigenDistance < _eigenDistanceThreshold )  ? _labels[index] : String.Empty; // <--- this one
```

whenever an unidentified person is detected

so to show that the person is "unknown" you could you this following code when your trying to detect and recognize a person

```
      ImageFrame.Draw(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? "UNKNOWN" : name, ref font, new Point(f.rect.X - 2, f.rect.Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.Green));
```

add this to your recognition form

hope that it helps